# Why does Chrome appear to fire user events?

Tags: javascript

I tried both `mousemove` and `click` and the event always fires on page load.

I even tried to put a 5 second delay on the bind, and the event still fires.

```
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('click');
            $(document).bind("click", self.intervalEnd());
        }, 5000);

    },
    intervalEnd: function(){
        console.log('intervalEnd called');
        console.log(this.intervalID);
        window.clearInterval(this.intervalID);
    },
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the event doesn't fire on pageload, but your function does execute on pageload, because that's what you told it to do.

Reference the function, instead of calling it, and use `on()`

```
$(document).on("click", self.intervalEnd);
```

Whenever you add parentheses to a function, you call it and return the result, so your code is the same as

```
var result = self.intervalEnd(); // most likely returns undefined
$(document).bind("click", result); // still undefined
```

Comment: Typo.  I know this.  Thank you for your diligence.

Comment: Best mark it as solved, then. And give @adeneo the answer.